# Is algebraic closure necessary? (3.6.K Ravi Vakil's notes)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've just done exercise 3.6.K in Ravi Vakil's notes and noticed that my solution does not seem to rely on algebraic closure, so I'd like a sanity check.  I understand it's important to make the "classical" points the only closed points, but it seems like an extraneous assumption for the problem at hand?  The problem is:

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra with $\mathfrak{N}(A) = \{0\}$.  Show that functions on $\operatorname{Spec}A$ are determined by their values on the closed points.

My attempt is that for two different $f,g\in A$, $\operatorname{D}(f-g)$ is nonempty since there are no nilpotents, so exercise 3.6.J(a) should apply immediately...

Comment: I believe the point is that finitely generated $k$-algebras are Jacobson rings, so yes, it suffices to assume that $k$ is a field.

Answer (score 3):

1) For an arbitrary field $k$, classes in $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ are certainly not determined by their associated functions on the classical points $V(I)\subset k^n$.
For example if $k=\mathbb F_2, n=1, I=(0)$, the polynomials $x$ and $x^2$ give rise to the same function on $k^1=\mathbb F_2$.

2) However the associated functions on $\operatorname {Specmax(A)}$ do determine the elements in $A$.
The point (as noted by Zhen) is that an element $\phi=\bar f\in A=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ which is zero at all points $[\mathfrak m]\in \operatorname {Specmax(A)}$ corresponding to maximal ideals $\mathfrak m\subset A$ is an element in the Jacobson radical $J=\cap_{\mathfrak m\in \operatorname {Specmax(A)}} \mathfrak m$, which  is known to be zero  for **reduced** finitely generated algebras over a field.

3) In particular if $k$ is algebraically closed, the (weak) Nullstellensatz states that the maximal ideals of $A$ correspond to the points of $V(I)\subset k^n$, so that the elements of $A$ are completely determined by their associated functions on $V(I)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the exact phrasing of the question tries to push you to view the elements of $k^n$ as being classical, and then to note that those correspond to the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ when $k = \bar{k}$ and that evaluation is then the obvious map into $k$.

I guess I've never thought of closed points in general as being all that classical -- I don't see how to easily interpret $(x^2 - 2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as something having just a single set of coordinates in some affine space. There's some sort of gluing going on.

On the other hand, the hypothesis is a little misleading and I agree that your argument works for any $k$ as long as "value" is interpreted suitably. You might write to Ravi suggesting that the question begin in a more general setting and then proceed to a discussion of the "classical" case. I do think the general fact is useful at a few other places in the notes.